# How to animate parent width depending on its content?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, keyframe

I have a modal whose content can be toggled between two different components. It works, but the transition is brutal since the wrapper immediately takes the width of its content.

How to animate this properly? I thought about transform:scale but it did not work.

Here is the code, as well as a sandbox:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components"

const Wrapper = styled.div`
background:gainsboro;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:1px solid lightgrey;
`

const Content1 = () => (
  <div>
    Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor sit amet, ass adipiscing elizzle. Ass 
    izzle velizzle, volutpizzle, suscipit quizzle, we gonna chung 
    vizzle, arcu. Pellentesque egizzle boom shackalack. Fo shizzle 
    my nizzle erizzle. Pimpin' crunk dolor dapibus rizzle tempizzle

    sizzle. Maurizzle fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home 
    g-dizzle nibh daahng dawg go to hizzle. Shizznit izzle tortor.
     Pellentesque sizzle rhoncizzle shizzlin dizzle. In hizzle 
     habitasse platea dictumst. For sure fo. Break it down izzle 

     urna, pretizzle eu, mattis go to hizzle, eleifend black, nunc.
      Daahng dawg suscipit. Tellivizzle yo mamma velit sed check 
      out this.
    </div>
)

const Content2 = () => (
  <div>
    very short content
    </div>
)

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
  return (
    <Wrapper>
     {toggle ? <Content1 /> : <Content2/>}
     <button onClick={()=> setToggle(!toggle)}>toggle content</button>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-smoke-5ikkg?file=/src/App.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-fade-in, not the best, but a fast solution

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fade-in

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure a fading is great solution since I want to animate the parent width. Also, a pure css/js solution would be better.